# SocketStream - Detect when client disconnect from server side

Tags: node.js, socketstream

Is there a way to detect when a client disconnect from the server side?

app.js

ss.event.on("close",function(session){

console.log(client disconnected);
});

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check these two:

```
req.on("close", function() {
  // request closed unexpectedly
});

req.on("end", function() {
  // request ended normally
}):
```

Comment: great, check the documentation to see each event from the clases. http://nodejs.org/api/index.html

Comment: what I want to do it's keep a online user list updated, so i guess i have to use the two events.

Comment: Could you get this to work anyhow? Federico's link has nothing to do with SocketStream, and `req` has no `on` member, and `ss` has no `event` member either. Is this about SS0.3?

Comment: @HenriqueEMota after some fiddling I figured you meant HTTP router's req. Unfortunately, req ends/closes as soon as the main view is sent, so it won't work for me. How did you get it to work?